# especificar un formato de fecha latinoamericano para el parseo de JSON usando JSON-B

Tags: java, json, jsonb-api

Tengo la siguiente entidad:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class AnswerData {
    @JsonbDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date theDate;
    private Integer answerIdx;
    private String answer;
}
```

Para verificar la serialización me hice la siguiente prueba unitaria

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import java.util.Date;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class AnswerDataTest {

    @Test
    void parsingOfDate() throws Exception {
        AnswerData answerData;
        try (Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create()) {
            answerData = jsonb.fromJson("{\n" +
                                        "  \"theDate\": \"06/04/2023\",\n" +
                                        "  \"answerIdx\": null,\n" +
                                        "  \"answer\": null\n" +
                                        "}", AnswerData.class);
        }
        assertEquals(new AnswerData(new Date(2023, 4, 6), null, null), answerData);

    }
}
```

El problema es que estoy obteniendo el siguiente error

> javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to deserialize property 'theDate' because of: Error parsing class java.util.Date from value: 06/04/2023. Check your @JsonbDateFormat has all time units for class java.util.Date type, or consider using org.eclipse.yasson.YassonConfig#ZERO_TIME_PARSE_DEFAULTING.

Comment: Puede ser que el formato de fecha proporcionado sea incorrecto? Has probado el formato MM/dd/yyyy  o sea  "  \"theDate\": \"04/06/2023\",\n" +

Comment: @DevMind sí claro ya lo probé